# Fail2ban - stop DOS attack from remote host - won't start

Tags: fail2ban

**SOLUTION**

##To stop DOS attack from remote host.

```
[http-get-dos] 
enabled = true 
port = http,https 
filter = http-get-dos 
logpath = /var/log/apache*/access.log 
maxretry = 400 
findtime = 400 
bantime = 200 
ignoreip = 127.0.0.1
action = iptables[name=HTTP, port=http, protocol=tcp]
```

**OS:** Ubuntu Server 20.10

**Http server:** Apache

When I add the rule (to stop DOS attack from remote host) to jail.conf, fail2ban stops working.
I got such a configuration in a few tutorials but they were Ubuntu 16 and 18.

```
enabled = true 
port = http,https 
filter = http-get-dos 
logpath = /var/log/apache*/access.log 
maxretry = 400 
findtime = 400 
bantime = 200 
ignoreip = 127.0.0.1
action = iptables[name=HTTP, port=http, protocol=tcp]
```

---

```
/etc/fail2ban/filter.d
```

---

```
http-get-dos.conf
```

---

```
# Fail2Ban configuration file 
[Definition]
failregex = ^<HOST> -.*"(GET|POST).* 
ignoreregex =
```

**sudo systemctl status fail2ban**

```
● fail2ban.service - Fail2Ban Service
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/fail2ban.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2021-01-07 09:05:29 UTC; 1h 23min ago
       Docs: man:fail2ban(1)
    Process: 82878 ExecStartPre=/bin/mkdir -p /run/fail2ban (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 82879 ExecStart=/usr/bin/fail2ban-server -xf start (code=exited, status=255/EXCEPTION)
   Main PID: 82879 (code=exited, status=255/EXCEPTION)

Jan 07 09:05:29 urial systemd[1]: Starting Fail2Ban Service...
Jan 07 09:05:29 urial systemd[1]: Started Fail2Ban Service.
Jan 07 09:05:29 urial fail2ban-server[82879]: 2021-01-07 09:05:29,370 fail2ban                [82879]: ERROR   Failed during configuration: While reading from '/etc/fail2ban/jail.local' [l>
Jan 07 09:05:29 urial fail2ban-server[82879]: 2021-01-07 09:05:29,372 fail2ban                [82879]: ERROR   Async configuration of server failed
Jan 07 09:05:29 urial systemd[1]: fail2ban.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=255/EXCEPTION
Jan 07 09:05:29 urial systemd[1]: fail2ban.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

**/etc/fail2ban$ cat jail.local**

```
wlodek@urial:/etc/fail2ban$ cat jail.local
 ##To block failed login attempts use the below jail. 
[sshd]
enable = true
port = ssh
filter = sshd
logpath = /var/log/auth.log
maxretray = 3
findtime = 300
bandtime = 86400
ignoreip = 127.0.0.1  

##To block failed login attempts use the below jail. 
[apache] 
enabled = true 
port = http,https 
filter = apache-auth 
logpath = /var/log/apache2/*error.log 
maxretry = 3 
bantime = 600 
ignoreip = 127.0.0.1
 
##To block the remote host that is trying to request suspicious URLs, use the below jail. 
[apache-overflows] 
enabled = true 
port = http,https 
filter = apache-overflows 
logpath = /var/log/apache2/*error.log 
maxretry = 3 
bantime = 600 
ignoreip = 127.0.0.1
 
##To block the remote host that is trying to search for scripts on the website to execute, use the below jail. 
[apache-noscript] 
enabled = true 
port = http,https 
filter = apache-noscript 
logpath = /var/log/apache2/*error.log 
maxretry = 3 
bantime = 600 
ignoreip = 127.0.0.1
 
##To block the remote host that is trying to request malicious bot, use below jail. 
[apache-badbots] 
enabled = true 
port = http,https 
filter = apache-badbots 
logpath = /var/log/apache2/*error.log 
maxretry = 3 
bantime = 600 
ignoreip = 127.0.0.1
 
##To stop DOS attack from remote host. [http-get-dos] 
enabled = true 
port = http,https 
filter = http-get-dos 
logpath = /var/log/apache*/access.log 
maxretry = 400 
findtime = 400 
bantime = 200 
ignoreip = 127.0.0.1
action = iptables[name=HTTP, port=http, protocol=tcp]
```

Comment: @tater added jail.local

Comment: @tater  everything works except `##To stop DOS attack from remote host. [http-get-dos] `

Comment: The section heading is on the same line as the comment, is it like that for real?

Comment: @tater  which file do you mean? jail.local? http-get-dos.conf?

Comment: The line you quoted in the comment, the `[http-get-dos]` in `jail.local` is on the same line as the comment, meaning it is ignored.

Comment: @tater I can't believe I looked at it 100 times and didn't notice it :)

Comment: @tater  write an answer and I will give you `+`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `jail.local` file, the jail section heading is on the same line as the comment:

```
##To stop DOS attack from remote host. [http-get-dos] 
enabled = true 
port = http,https 
filter = http-get-dos 
logpath = /var/log/apache*/access.log 
maxretry = 400 
findtime = 400 
bantime = 200 
ignoreip = 127.0.0.1
action = iptables[name=HTTP, port=http, protocol=tcp]
```

This means the section heading is being ignored.  It should be put on a separate line like so:

```
##To stop DOS attack from remote host.
[http-get-dos] 
enabled = true 
port = http,https 
filter = http-get-dos 
logpath = /var/log/apache*/access.log 
maxretry = 400 
findtime = 400 
bantime = 200 
ignoreip = 127.0.0.1
action = iptables[name=HTTP, port=http, protocol=tcp]
```